# Selenium tests do not work on IE8

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-8, webdriver, ie8-compatibility-mode

To test some of the legacy pages I need to execute few test cases against `IE8`. These same testcases run efficiently against `IE10/11, FF, Chrome` without any issue.

```
public void TypePassword(string password)
{
    var element = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(
        ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//input[@id='txtPassword']")));

    //I also tried with just id and cssselector

    element.Clear();
    element.SendKeys(password);
}
```

I also tried

```
public void TypePassword(string password)
{
    Password.Clear();
    Password.SendKeys(password);
}
```

Interestingly,

```
public void TypeUsername(string username)
{
    Username.Clear();
    Username.SendKeys(username);
}
```

always work without any issue.

```
The IE driver configuration
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions { EnableNativeEvents = false};
options.AddAdditionalCapability("EnsureCleanSession", true);
Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

Seems like I am missing some configuration which is specific to IE8.

Also, confirmed zoom level and protected mode set up

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried JavascriptExecutor ?

```
var element = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//input[@id='txtPassword']")));
((JavascriptExecutor)Driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value='"+password+"'", element);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's not an option. I don't want to rewrite the whole test suit only for IE8.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know it would. But, the problem is I just do not want to rewrite the existing test cases. I have over 300+ test cases. Now for that I have to revisit all of them and tweak them with JavaScript which I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to find the element exists,

so u  can go for the element count >1 using do while loop,

```
do
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}while(driver.FindElements(By.Id("IDNAME")).Count>0);
```

Unless until, the count of the element gets, this do loop will execute and wait for the element to visible also